# MacOS and OpenCV

Tags: macos, opencv

Morning SO.

I would like to compile openCV to make it work on a webcam capture using Qt 4.7. For that purpose, OpenCV must be compiled for a 64bit system.

So, I've tried 3 compilations :

- Compiling from the source with cmake :

  ```
  sudo cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .
  ```

  it works, but I can't dump a video into a file using cvCreateVideoWriter :
  the output file is empty.
- using macports :

  ```
  sudo port install opencv
  ```

  it's not that great because it depends on gtk2, ffmpeg and the libX .. and there is no image captured.
- using the compiled framework

  the framework is compiled for 32 bit system only.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on macports opencv install? I think it could not be the issue anymore but I may misunderstand your problem. With OpenCV2.4.2+tbb I have great performance and it seems to be fully functional, also wrote Qt+OpenCV programs capturing webcam stream.

On the other hand I could not make OpenCV+python work. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using opencv-cocoa does the trick !

http://code.google.com/p/opencv-cocoa/

Answer (score 0):

I think CMake is the best choice.
Your problem with cvCreateVideoWriter is probably related to a missing video codec.